# MySQL not recognizing virtual column / field

Tags: mysql, subquery, virtual, field

I'm trying to manipulate two virtual fields generated of a subquery into a new field, but MySQL is telling me that "GP" is an unknown column, but it has been already declared. Please, take a look at my query:

```
SELECT *,

(SELECT COUNT(id_gol) FROM tb_gol as gol
INNER JOIN tb_jogo as jg ON(gol.fk_id_jogo = jg.id_jogo)
WHERE gol.ic_excluido != '*' AND gol.fk_id_equipe = e.id_equipe AND jg.fk_id_campeonato = g.fk_id_campeonato) as 'GP',

(SELECT COUNT(id_gol) FROM tb_gol as gol
INNER JOIN tb_jogo as jg ON(gol.fk_id_jogo = jg.id_jogo)
WHERE gol.ic_excluido != '*' AND gol.fk_id_equipe != e.id_equipe AND (jg.fk_id_equipe1 = e.id_equipe OR jg.fk_id_equipe2 = e.id_equipe) AND jg.fk_id_campeonato = g.fk_id_campeonato) as 'GC',

(SELECT COUNT(id_wo) as WOs FROM tb_wo as w INNER JOIN tb_jogo as j ON (w.fk_id_jogo = j.id_jogo) WHERE w.fk_id_equipe = e.id_equipe AND j.fk_id_campeonato = g.fk_id_campeonato) as 'WO',

(GP+(GC*-1)) as 'SALDO'

FROM tb_equipe as e
INNER JOIN tb_gruposEquipes as ge ON (e.id_equipe = ge.fk_id_equipe)
INNER JOIN tb_grupos as g ON (g.id_grupo = ge.fk_id_grupo)
WHERE g.fk_id_campeonato = 23
ORDER BY WO ASC
```

As you can see, "SALDO" would be the result of "GP-GC". But MySQL do not recognize these columns

How can I solve this?

**SOLUTION**

Thanks a lot for the help, guys, but I figured out the problem.
"SALDO" couldn't be created by substracting GC of GP because "GP" and "GC" doesn't exist during runtime.

So, when you need to manipulate virtual fields during the runtime, you'll have to repeat the code that generated the virtual field.

Then, if you have this select:

```
SELECT *, (field1+1) as 'GP', (field2+1) as 'GC', (GP+GC) as 'SALDO' FROM (...)
```

You'll need to replace it with this:

```
SELECT *, (field1+1) as 'GP', (field2+1) as 'GC', ((field1+1)+(field2+1)) as 'SALDO' FROM (...)
```

Comment: An alias can be used in a query select list to give a column a different name. You can use the alias in `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, or `HAVING` clauses to refer to the column. Look at manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html . Are you using this query in some kind of script or is it just sql?

Comment: Can you add the table structures of `tb_equipe`, `tb_gruposEquipes` and `tb_grupos`. This is a nifty little web app to help group debugging: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 1):

Push the stuff into in inner query

```
    SELECT core.*,
    (GP+(GC*-1)) as 'SALDO'

    from (

    (SELECT COUNT(id_gol) FROM tb_gol as gol
    INNER JOIN tb_jogo as jg ON(gol.fk_id_jogo = jg.id_jogo)
    WHERE gol.ic_excluido != '*' AND gol.fk_id_equipe = e.id_equipe AND jg.fk_id_campeonato = g.fk_id_campeonato) as 'GP',

    (SELECT COUNT(id_gol) FROM tb_gol as gol
    INNER JOIN tb_jogo as jg ON(gol.fk_id_jogo = jg.id_jogo)
    WHERE gol.ic_excluido != '*' AND gol.fk_id_equipe != e.id_equipe AND (jg.fk_id_equipe1 = e.id_equipe OR jg.fk_id_equipe2 = e.id_equipe) AND jg.fk_id_campeonato = g.fk_id_campeonato) as 'GC',

    (SELECT COUNT(id_wo) as WOs FROM tb_wo as w INNER JOIN tb_jogo as j ON (w.fk_id_jogo = j.id_jogo) WHERE w.fk_id_equipe = e.id_equipe AND j.fk_id_campeonato = g.fk_id_campeonato) as 'WO' ) 


    FROM tb_equipe as e

    ) as core 
    INNER JOIN tb_gruposEquipes as ge ON (core.id_equipe = ge.fk_id_equipe)
    INNER JOIN tb_grupos as g ON (g.id_grupo = ge.fk_id_grupo)
    WHERE g.fk_id_campeonato = 23
    ORDER BY WO ASC
```